# My website looks different in Firefox from Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've been working on a webpage on Chrome and realized it doesn't look the same in Firefox. I have simplified my code to show the problem. It seems the last  is not displayed in Firefox whilst it is visible in Chrome.

Here is my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">



  <div id=shipBoard align="right" style="overflow: hidden">

    <div id="ship" style="float: left;">
      <img src="carrier.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    </div>

    <div id="ship" style="float: left;">
      <img src="destroyer.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    </div>

    <div id="ship" style="float: left;">
      <img src="test.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    </div>

    <div id="ship" style="float: left;">
      <img src="battleship.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    </div>

    <div id="ship" style="float: left;">
      <img src="sub.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    </div>

  </div>

</html>
```

And here is the css file:

```
#ship {
  position: relative;
  width: 4cm;
  height: 5cm;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

#shipBoard {
  position: relative;
  width: 20cm;
  height: 5cm;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

What can I do to make them the same?

Comment: You should start by having a valid HTML file, with a `<head>` and a `<body>`.

Comment: @ceejayoz Those tags are optional.

Comment: I would start by looking into a CSS Reset or Normalize (Ask Google). These CSS snippets try to level out the foundation so that each browser acts roughly the same for all elements. Additionally using real-world measurements like `cm` are likely to cause differences between devices/browsers. Instead you should use screen based units like `px` or better yet relative units like `% em rem vw/vh`

Comment: @JoshLee The W3C's HTML5 validator says "Element `head` is missing a required instance of child element `title`" for this HTML.

Comment: Also it would help if you could post screenshots of the differences you see.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, the _title_ element is required.

Comment: @JoshLee i.e. they have an invalid HTML5 document. Given OP's having browser rendering issues, explicitly declaring what's head/body is a worthwhile first step to reduce browser differences.

Comment: @ceejayoz The meta and link elements are in the head, and the div is in the body. No browser gets this wrong, and it's not even a validation error, just a common misconception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subpixel positioning is tricky. The `cm` unit doesn't map to a whole number of pixels (It's defined as `1cm = 96px/2.54`).

In Chrome:

```
> getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#shipBoard')).width
"755.891px"
> getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#ship')).width
"151.172px"
```

In Firefox:

```
> getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#shipBoard')).width
"755.9px"
> getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#ship')).width
"151.183px"
```

Values in CSS layout are often converted from doubles to floats and back, or rounded to a few decimal places. This layout is brittle because it depends on 5*width(ship) ≤ width(shipBoard). Floats are designed to wrap when necessary. Certain lengths in CSS, particularly borders, occasionally snap to a whole number of pixels regardless of zoom level.

Flexbox or grid would be a good choice instead of floats, but changing the width properties to `151px` and `755px` in your CSS fixes this.

Also, don't use the same `id=` on multiple elements, it's not valid.

Answer (score -4):

You can't. Usually, in HTML it can display differently on different browsers. Firefox isn't as advanced as Chrome in this area.

Comment: That's simply false.

Comment: This isn't really true. In most cases and with effort, you can make almost all browsers look exactly the same. It's a fool's errand but it can be done. That said, well written HTML & CSS should look very similar across Grade A browsers and that includes Firefox, Safari and Edge in addition to Chrome.

Comment: I apologize. From my understanding that was how it worked.